Get updated data after updating it and filtering React JS
I have an existing code here that update employee and show the updated employee. I also have a filter dropdowns that filters the data but after filtering the data and updating it. It only shows the updated filtered data due to the setEmployees(newEmployees).
function updateEmployee(index, employee) {
        const newEmployees = employees.slice();
        newEmployees[index] = employee;
        setEmployees(newEmployees);
        //setEmployees(updatedEmployee and all the data)
 }

What I want to happen is after updating it. The previous data is still there as well as the updated one

The outcome you're looking for is vague. Are you implying that the employee param should be appended to the current list of employees, or that it only contains a partial update of the employee located at index?
